# Unable to parse xml with different vale of name in android

Tags: java, android, xml

My xml code is this:-

```
 <MMP>
   <script id="tinyhippos-injected"/>
     <MERCHANT>
       <RESPONSE>
          <url>https://www.google.com</url>
            <param name="ttype">NBFundTransfer</param>
            <param name="tempTxnId">650398</param>
            <param name="token">7OhXxW7ndM0Ft%2B02bkgIHB0N0eKAMeiA2oeAjwTjiS</param>
            <param name="txnStage">1</param>
      </RESPONSE>
     </MERCHANT>
</MMP>
```

Here I want the value of all token , txnStage

And my android code is :-

```
  try {
            URL url = new URL(URL1);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            // Download the XML file
            doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            // Locate the Tag Name
            nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("RESPONSE");
           for (int temp = 0; temp < nodelist.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nodelist.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                // Set the texts into TextViews from item nodes
                // Get the title
                textview.setText(textview.getText() + "Title : "
                        +eElement.getAttribute("name") + "\n" + "\n");
             }
           }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Using this code I'm not getting any value in my textview.
Anyone have any idea, Please share

Comment: `if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { `condition is executing or not?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, Yes it is executing ,  textview.setText( "Title : "
                            +getNode("url", eElement) + "\n" + "\n");   I'm getting the value of url but not the token

Comment: Means getting `Title :` in TextView?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK , Only title as a text which i'm putting..

Comment: Or if I'm putting param then I'm only getting first value that is:- NBFundTransfer......

Comment: ok try it as ` Node nNode = nodelist.item(temp);
 NodeList nodeList=nNode.getElementsByTagName("param");
 for(int count=0;count<nodeList.getLength(); count++) {
    textview.setText(textview.getText() + "Title : "
                        +nodeList.item(count).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue() + "\n" + "\n");
 }`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, I'm getting the param name like ttype , token only....

Answer (score 0):

It looks that your `nodelist` collection contains only one item - representing the `<RESPONSE>` element. This element does not have the attribute `name` set - so nothing gets populated.